# Pyinstaller | Extrected Exe unable to find sub module

Tags: python-2.7, python-import, pyinstaller

I am new in Python. Currently Using Python 2.7. As a current exercise I am converting Python Script to exe file through PyInstaller. I am finding trouble in finding certain modules through generated exe which are working perfectly fine while I am running through Python Script.

I have created exe through --onefile option in PyInstaller. As a part of exercise I have already done the following points,

1. Verified that python file is exist at particular locaion(temp location) including python compiled file.
2. I updated sys.path entries to find python at particular(temp) location.
3. I also verified that imp.findModules able to find the module but imp.loadModule failed to load the module while running through exe file.
4. Note that while I am running the python file from command line it works   fine, it only gives error while I am creating exe file.

   [Problem Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4rLs.png) is attached here. 
   Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,
Sunay Shah

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have seen that many people are facing the issue. I fixed the Issue and following is the solution for the same.

During packaging with the help of PyInstaller , I found out that PyInstaller is analyzing the given python file and imports packages itself which it found during the analysis phase. Those which packages which are found and would be zipped during the packaging can be seen in the build folder created by PyInstaller (out00-Analysis.toc,out00-PKG.toc,out00-PYZ.toc,out01-Tree.toc,warnXXX.txt file ) are the important files to look into.

During my problem analysis I found that my certain packages are not imported during the Analysis phase. I came to know on digging that we need to include those packages in data files. So I copied almost all my packages that are required into data section in .spec file. Still problem continues. I dig little more and found that although artifacts are packaged they are unable to import during execution.

I gone through some in more details and found out that issue was around that during runtime certain modules were not able to import by PyInstaller. I found that issue can be resolved with the help of hidden-imports. I added missing modules in hidden-import section which resolved the issue.

Making Long story short , following are the key take away from my problem 
  1. Create a Build with default option , resolve all your problems
  2. Include all the required modules into the build with datas section which were not found out by PyInstaller.
  3. Add hidden imports which were not imported by Pyinstaller. ( e.g if   abc.contrib.usages module is not loaded during runtime, add that into hiddeniports sectin.
 4. Once created exe works with default option use --onefile to create the build.
5. Best way to resolve your problems is analyze all the files created in build folder during the creation of the build.

Hope this will help some one to fix there issues.

Regards,
Sunay Shah

Comment: Hi, Cab you please provide your .spec file here for the reference